# What are the differences between ～ばいい, ～たらいい, and ～たほうがいい?

Tags: grammar

For giving advice, what are their different nuances?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40087/9831

Answer (score 1):

"～ばいい": recommendation. You should do it.

"厳しいドレスコードはないよ。ネクタイをしていればいいよ。"

There is no strict dress code. You just should wear a tie.

"～たらいい": recommendation. You should have done it.

"Ｔシャツとジーンズじゃ、カジュアルすぎるね。せめてネクタイをしてたらいいのに。"

Your T-shirt and jeans are too casual. The least you could do is to ware a tie.

"～たほうがいい" : reccomendation. You should do it.

"服装については何も言われてないけど、多分、ネクタイはしてたほうがいいよ。" = "服装については何も言われてないけど、多分、ネクタイはしたほうがいいよ。"

There is no doress code cleary expressed, but probably you should wear a tie.

All are colloquial expression.