# Asking for advice/suggestion "should I...?"

Tags: grammar, syntax

みなさん,こんにちは。

I was wondering what gramatical structure is best to use when asking for advice as we would in English with 'Should I...?' Or 'should we...?'.
I've come across two possible choices but I'm not sure what nuance each structure brings to the sentence. ' ーた ほう が いい です か'  and 'ーたら いい です か'

What's should I use if I want to say these simple phrases for example:

1. Should I take of my shoes?
2. Should I open the window?
3. Should we go to the cinema?

My attempts:

1. (私は)靴を脱いだほうがいいですか。
2. 窓を開いたらいいですか。
3. (私たちは)映画館へ行ったらいいですか。

Thanks in advance guys. 
よろしくお願いします!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between ”conditional” いい and 方がいい for providing recommendations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/difference-between-conditional-%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-and-%e6%96%b9%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-for-providing-recommendations) (though your question does address advice/questions more specifically)

Comment: `2. 窓を開いたらいいですか。` ← Do you mean  [開]{ひら}いたら or [開]{あ}いたら ?

Comment: Thanks for linking henreetee, just what I was looking for!

Comment: Hey Chocolate, I think 'あいたら' is the one I mean. From the verb stem ' to open' if I'm not mistaken? Cheers.

Comment: to be honest, [開]{あ}いたら is also unusual because [開]{あ}く is intransitive verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m Japanese naitive speaker and I don’t study linguistics.
So I write my impression and opinion to your attempt.

1「靴を脱いだほうがいいですか」
This is correct and natural sentence because you have now two choices take off your shoes or not.

2「窓を[開]{あ}いたらいいですか」
I think this is a little bit unnatural. first, 窓を[開]{あ}いたら is unusual. 窓を[開]{あ}けis natural. 
Now your choice is two 窓を[開]{あ}ける or [開{あ}けない. So I think 窓を[開]{あ}けたほうがいいですか？ is natural.
this is just my impressions, there are possibilities that when you say 窓を[開]{あ}けたらいいですか？ ,  a few people feel you are irritated. I think this depends on your attitude and facial expression .

3 Sorry, I can’t understand the situation so I can’t judge this is natural or not. But In this case if you have two choice 映画館にいく or 行かない. So 行ったほうがいいですか is more polite expression.

P.S.
I learned that my feelings that 窓を[開]{ひら}く is unusual is not common sense.
This online Japanese dictionary says that 窓を[開]{あ}ける and 窓を[開]{ひら}く is both used. [https://kotobank.jp/word/明ける-423836](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%98%8E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-423836)

Comment: `窓を開く is unusual. 窓を開ける is natural.` ←　質問者が 「窓を[開]{あ}く」ではなく「窓を[開]{ひら}く」を意図したという可能性はないでしょうか？

Comment: @Chocolate 私は日本語の専門家でもないのでなんとも言えないのですが、西洋風のお屋敷にありそうな観音開きの窓を除けば多くの場合、窓をひらく というのはあまり日常で言わないような気がしたのです。。。

Comment: 回答の中の文は、『窓を[開]{ひら}いたらいいですか I think this is a little bit unnatural. first, 窓を[開]{ひら}く is unusual. 窓を[開]{あ}ける is natural.』だったのですね。。ここ、フリガナがあったほうがいいかもしれませんね。

Comment: なるほど、たしかに仰る通りです。編集しておきます。